# HTML button inside the anchor

Tags: php, html

I m using a button inside anchor

Here is code

```
<a href="<?php echo $INCLUDE_ROOT_DIRECTORY. 'mailer_add_contents.php'; ?>" >
   <input type="button" value="Add Contents" style="float: right; margin-top: 5px;" class="button_link" />
```

This code is not working in IE. I m clicking on button but it does not go anywhere.

Comment: look's like your button is not inside the `<a>`, try `<a><input /></a>`

Comment: Try validating your HTML document...I'm fairly sure that having `<input>` within `<a>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: OK. So you are writing [invalid code](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) that isn't supposed to work (The a element: Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.). What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can add `onclick` attribute to button to redirect rather than wrapping it in link:

```
<input type="button" onclick = "window.location = '<?php echo $INCLUDE_ROOT_DIRECTORY. 'mailer_add_contents.php'; ?>'" />
```

Comment: Placing an URL inside `onclick` will do nothing but throw an error.